# React native Hide selected item list of SectionedMultiSelect

Tags: react-native

I want to hide selected item list of `SectionedMultiSelect` in react native and how to apply styles to this component how can I do this?
Can anyone help me to do this?

```
<SectionedMultiSelect
          items={days}
          uniqueKey="id"
          hideSearch={true}
          subKey="day"
          selectText="Select Days..."
          showDropDowns={true}
          readOnlyHeadings={true}
          onSelectedItemsChange={this.onSelectedItemsChange}
          selectedItems={this.state.selectedItems}
          // styles={}
        />
```

I want to hide that highlighted portion of image:

[image: I want to hide that highlighted portion of image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
              <SectionedMultiSelect
                  items={items}
                  IconRenderer={Icon}
                  uniqueKey="id"
                  // subKey="children"
                  selectText="Click to select Expertise"
                  showDropDowns={true}
                  onSelectedItemsChange={(selectedItems) => {
                    setDidUpdate(true);
                    setExpertise(selectedItems)
                  }}
                  showChips={false}
                  selectedItems={expertise}
                  colors= {{
                    selectToggleTextColor: 'red'
                  }}
                  styles={{
                    // chipText: {
                    //   maxWidth: Dimensions.get('screen').width - 90,
                    // },
                    chipContainer : {
                      // backgroundColor: 'red',
                      // color: 'green',
                      borderRadius: 16,
                      borderWidth: 2,
                      borderColor: 'white',
                      marginTop: 10
                    },
                    chipText: {
                      color: 'white',
                    },
                    chipIcon: {
                      color: 'white',
                    },
                    button: {
                      backgroundColor: '#FF9017',
                    },
                    selectToggle: {
                      color: 'white',
                    },
                    selectToggleText: {
                      color: 'white',
                      // backgroundColor: 'red',
                      borderWidth: 2,
                      borderRadius:25,
                      borderColor: '#fff',
                      padding: 5,
                      paddingLeft: 15
                    },
                  }}
                />
```

Setting showChips to false will hide the selected items list and check my styles and the documentation for more help.
https://github.com/renrizzolo/react-native-sectioned-multi-select

Comment: Perfect Solution :)